# I am getting Status Code: 403 when I am calling an api using jquery in BigCommerce to get complex-rules

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-status-code-403, bigcommerce

I am trying to get the weight of products added to the cart along with the weight set in the rules from the bigcommerce backend.

I have already tried a numerous times and finally got the weight using the api 
"internalapi/v1/catalog/products/{product_id}/complex-rules" but i am getting 403 forbidden error even though i have set the credentials in the headers part during the api call. 
I am getting the desired output when I am logged into the bigCommerce sandbox but when i get into private mode or incognito mode, i receive 403 error in the console.

Hereby is my code.
The api url is returning a 403() error.
I have removed the product-id and the tokens as such they are confidential .

```
var settings = {
              "async": false,
              "crossDomain": true,
              "url": "internalapi/v1/catalog/products/{product_id}/complex-rules",
              "method": "GET",
              "headers": {
                "accept": "application/json",
                "content-type": "application/json",
                "x-auth-client": "{CLIENT}",
                "x-auth-token": "{TOKEN}"

              },
              "processData": false
            }
            $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
                var getData = response['data']; 
                console.log('For Rule', getData );
            });
```

I want the output to be the json response with the rules related to particular product.

Comment: I believe auth for that internal API endpoint is cookie based--that's why you're seeing 403 errors when incognito. Is it a requirement to make the request client-side? In most cases, we'd recommend making a server-to-server API call to our public APIs for rule data. https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/catalog/catalog-api/product-complex-rules/getcomplexrules

Comment: Hello , thank you for your reply. I had used the method that u suggested but it gave me CORS error and eventually it didn't work at all and yes the the request must be on client-side

Comment: Correct--our APIs don't support CORS and the API linked in the reference doc is meant to be called from a server, rather than the browser. It would be very insecure to expose Oauth tokens in a client-side request.

Answer (score 0):

Stencil utils returns a variant's weight from the [product attribute function](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/adding-event-hooks-to-your-theme/stencil-utils-api-reference#stencil-utils_product-attributes). I'd recommend this as a more standard way to get a variant's adjusted weight client-side. The function will return the weight for the selected SKU rather than an array of all rules for the product, and you won't need to supply any credentials to make this request.

Comment: Thanks a lot . It worked just the way I wanted it to .